# Removing points which fall outside of selected polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

I have a project of finding the safest and most convenient place to cycle in London. There is a polygon layer(the yellow polygons) of boroughs that have lower collision rate; and a points layer showing all the parking space (green points).

[image]

I wanted to show only points in yellow polygon, I have tried to use vector--> Geoprocessing tools --> clip, I used points layer as the input layer, and yellow polygon layer as the clip layer. But the result removed all the points on map.

Can someone tell which step did I do wrong ?

Comment: You may want to double-check that the two layers have the same coordinate reference system. I don't get any results from the clip tool if the CRS's of the layers are different.

Comment: thank you so! you are right, my two layers are in different CRS, I enabled "on the fly" reprojection, so I thought they are "automatically" transformed into the same CRS, but when I re-read the documentation, I found you need to change CRS manually! That was a big misunderstanding! thank you so much for reminding me that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to select the point withing the yellow polygon feature using Select by location tool from `Vector -> Research tools -> Select by location`

[image]

- In the `Select feature in`: select the point feature
- Select the polygon feature in the `that intersect features in`
- If the points located within selected polygon features (not as separate polygon layer), then you need to check `Only selected feature` located at the bottom
- Then save the selected point as new shapefile from `Right-click the point layer -> Save as -> Check save only selected features`

[image]

You need to make sure that both point and polygon shapefiles have the same CRS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed your steps and it worked !